# managed c++ string compare working oddly

Tags: .net, c++-cli, visual-c++-2010, base-class-library

I am trying to compare 2 strings but getting weird results. On some computers, the comparison works correctly and on others, it does not. The codes is written in Visual Studio 2010 using managed C++.I have checked the strings and they look identical. Any thoughts?

```
String^ str1 = "string1";
char[] chars = "string1";
String^ str2 = new String(chars);
if(String::Compare(str1,str2)==0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Comment: `String::Compare` is culture-sensitive; if you want to use an invariant culture then use a different overload taking `CultureInfo`.

Comment: I saw that but I'm not very familiar with cultures. How would I do that?

Comment: Calling [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06.aspx) with `StringComparison::InvariantCulture` is surely the easiest approach, but every overload comes with example code -- read the documentation.

Comment: InvariantCulture still fails. So do the rest.

Comment: Then you'll need to show more code that actually exhibits the problem (e.g. you're not even examining the result of `String::Compare` in the code you've shown). [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Regarding your edit, after correcting `char[] chars` to `char chars[]` and `new String` to `gcnew String`, I always get `true`. You need to post code that 1) actually compiles and 2) returns `false` erroneously.

Comment: It's difficult, because, like I said, this only happens on some machines. It works as expected on most, but on at least one machine, it does not.

Comment: Time to attach a debugger then!

Comment: So that's the really funny thing. If I put a break point at the compare line and step past it, it works fine, which made me think it might be some crazy timing issue, but putting a sleep before the compare does nothing.... So confused.

Comment: Actually, that's a good step towards figuring out the problem -- those symptoms are good indications of memory corruption. Have you run your program through a profiler that tracks memory usage/access?

Comment: No, I've never done that. Can you recommend one?

Comment: My personal experiences with SciTech .NET Memory Profiler have all been very positive, but I haven't tried much of the competition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with the char* conversion to a string. The char* array was not properly null terminated.